# regular expression to capture string after a regular pattern of string

Tags: regex

I need help for a regular expression.

we have the below string :

$VAR = [1550181700, '"xyz (gmail.com)" ', 'Hi Team,Please ON HOLD,HostName: kmkkmk.abc.com,Job Name: dat-inh-ndw-q9n580_prd106.f,Job Name: dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b,Job Name: dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b,regards,DSG Team']

in the above string, i need to capture anything after "Job Name: " and before next COMMA(,)
which means i have to get a list of string as output containing as below:
[dat-inh-ndw-q9n580_prd106.f,dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b,dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b]

note : we dont know how many times the "Job Name: " might occour in the above string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends a bit on your infrastructure. Basically, your Regex would look somewhat like this (.NET syntax assumed):

```
"Job Name:\\s*([^,]*)"
```

This will capture the string "JobName:" followed by any number of spaces. Then, we have a capturing group of any number of characters, that are not comma ([^,]*). Using this, you can start a matching process, that will give you all the strings you want in the first capturing group.

That's where the infrastructure comes in. Do you need it in a .NET context, or JavaScript, or PHP, or something else? The commands will differ depending on the used technology.

**UPDATE 1: (Perl code)**

```
$s = "$VAR = [1550181700, '\"xyz (gmail.com)\" ', 'Hi Team,Please ON HOLD,HostName: kmkkmk.abc.com,Job Name: dat-inh-ndw-q9n580_prd106.f,Job Name: dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b,Job Name: dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b,regards,DSG Team']";

@jobNames = [];
while($s =~ /Job Name:\s*([^,]*)/gi) {
    push @jobNames, $1;
}
```

This will give you all the names you need in the @jobNames array. However, if you need just the regex as a parameter to your function, we will probably need to change it a bit.

**UPDATE 2: (using lookbehind assertion)**

What you may actually be looking for is the so called zero-width look-behind assertion. It defines a pattern to be matched, but NOT included in the result. Then, the regex would look like this:

```
/(?<=Job Name: )[^,]*/
```

The `(?<=...)` construct tells the regex to only match the following pattern, if it is preceded by whatever is defined in the parentheses, in your case "Job Name: ". However, this should NOT be included in the result. So, only the rest of the pattern will be part of your result.

NOTE: You may have noticed, that I replaced the `\s*` construct after the colon by a regular space. This is because my online perl playground gave me a "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex" error when using the \s* construct. It may however work in your implementation of perl. If you are sure, there will always be exactly one space after the colon, you can just go ahead and use the single space.

Comment: Hi @chiristoph Herold
i need it in perl context.
I am using this regex in MRL language. it supports only perl syntax

Comment: Ok, I'm no perl expert, but the basic regex remains valid: `/Job Name:\s*([^,]*)/`. Not sure about what the command will look like.

Comment: See UPDATE 2: Look-behind assertions might be your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very helpful. This worked for me(Update2) :)
I use it in our function as  `if (match_regex ($EV.mc_long_msg,'(?<=Job Name: )[^,]*','',[$JOB_NAMES]))
  { action } `

Comment: why did i get negative on my question ? :( how do i avoid this in next asking questions !

Comment: Glad it helped. I don't know, why you got the negatives on your question. Probably, people consider it too specific, and too few details to give a meaningful answer (i.e. what I asked about the platform, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular expression: [`Job Name: (?<job>[^,]*)`](https://regexr.com/48fu1)

Comment: does the below is same ?
(Job Name: ([^,]*),)

Comment: Yes it's the same

Answer (score 0):

```
(?>Job Name: )([^,]*)
```

Captures these 3 strings:

```
dat-inh-ndw-q9n580_prd106.f
dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b
dat-inh-rdm-q9n717_jdapfrdly.b
```

Comment: It looks fine.. Thank you.
i need the whole regex with in parenthesis, as i need to pass this as an argument to a function in MRL language.
will it work the same way if i keep the whole thing in barckets like below :

((?>Job Name: )([^,]*))

Comment: I don't know what tools you're using, so I can't really answer that. You might be able to pass it around as a string, that's pretty standard. So then, in many languages, you would surround it with quotes. If you surround it with parens, depending on how it's processed, you may end up creating a new capture group of the whole string.

Comment: Thank you @Jwismar
how is **Job Name: ([^,]*),** different from **(?>Job Name: )([^,]*)**  ?
I request you to explain the difference and which do you think is better ?

Comment: (?>) creates what's called a "non-capturing group". I groups things together, but whatever matches inside it doesn't get added to your match results. In this case it's not necessary. The two expressions end up being equivalent. It would have been needed if you were repeating that group.